# Disable label edit in a MouseClick action

Tags: .net, winforms, listview, controls, treeview

In WinForms controls, how can I disable label edit when I click in an item of controls like ListView, TreeView, etc?, without disabling the editing capability (`LabelEdit` property)?

I want to do that because the following behaviour is anoying and problematic:  "Select an item of one of those control, change the focus to other application, click back in the item" and then the label edit start automatically. Perhaps I want to only recover the focus and the selection.

Something similar happens when you change focus between controls of the same app, but in this situation I stop this behaviour cleaning the items selection at the moment of entering the control.

For the first described problem that is useless.

Comment: Why do you want to disable this without disabling it? Turning off the `LabelEdit` property is *exactly* the solution you're looking for. You can still edit the label through code, the user just won't be able to do it by clicking on it.

Comment: XD @Cody you are right after write the question and go to visual, the solution comes to my mind, i disable labeledit by default, then if i press F2 i enable it and then call the BeginEdit() method. In the AfterLabelEdit event handler i disable it again.

Comment: That has side-effects, the native Windows control gets re-created when you do this.  You left some very important details out of this question, giving SO users little chance to help you.  Why don't you just give up on label editing, it is a pita for the user anyway.  Just display the text of the selected node in a TextBox.

Answer (score 2):

you can do that by  handling  BeforeLabelEdit of tree

```
    private void treeView1_BeforeLabelEdit(object sender, NodeLabelEditEventArgs e)
    {
//if you want to edit in some special case write your condition here
        e.CancelEdit = true;
    }
```